# Unable to define intent data to handle linkify intent

Tags: android, android-intent, linkify

I have an activity that contains the following filter:

```
 <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <data
            android:host="com.ibs.shababeek.search"
            android:path="/posts/*"
            android:scheme="content" />
    </intent-filter>
```

The linkfiy text fires this intent:

```
act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.ibs.shababeek.search/posts/#test
```

but it keeps telling me:  No Activity found to handle Intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:path="/posts/*"
```

You probably want `android:pathPattern`, not `android:path`.